# Flask form does not let me upload TSV files

Tags: html, flask, flask-wtforms

I have the following flask app where I want to be able to upload a TXT or TSV file to a form. The problem is, when I try to upload a TXT file, it works, but when I try to upload a TSV file, I get the following error:

```
  File "/Users/cdastmalchi/Desktop/author_script/main.py", line 89, in process_file
    if not places_exist(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)):
  File "/Users/cdastmalchi/Desktop/author_script/main.py", line 27, in places_exist
    infile = open(filename, 'rU')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './Authors_Template.tsv'
```

`Authors_Template.tsv` is a template file that gets downloaded from the form and goes into the `Downloads`, and then I want users to be able to edit this template and then re-upload it. When I make the template `Authors_Template.txt` instead and then Download and re-upload it, it works. How can I solve this problem? I've even tried narrowing down the `ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS` list to just `TSV` and I still get the same issue.

**app.py**

```
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import flask, string, random
import json
import subprocess
import os
import re
import time


UPLOAD_FOLDER = '.'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt','tsv'])

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.secret_key = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(20)) #needed to use flask.session



def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

def places_exist(filename):
    infile = open(filename, 'rU')

    placeDict = {}
    addresses_temp = []
    addresses = []
    places_temp =[]
    places = []
    places_exist = True

    for i in infile:
        item = i.rstrip("\n").split("\t")
        places_temp.append(item[0])
        addresses_temp.append(item[1])

    p_index = (places_temp.index('Place')) + 1
    a_index = (addresses_temp.index('Address')) + 1

    places = places_temp[p_index:]
    addresses = addresses_temp[a_index:]

    infile.close()

    infile = open(filename, 'rU')

    return places_exist

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
   return flask.render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/process_file', methods=['POST'])
def process_file():
  #here, you can run all the checks as before, but instead of flash, you can return jsonified results to read in the front-end
    if 'file' not in flask.request.files or not flask.request.files['file'].filename:
        return flask.jsonify({'result':'False', 'message':'no files selected'})
        return flask.redirect(url_for('home'))
    file = flask.request.files['file']
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    if not allowed_file(file.filename):
        return flask.jsonify({'result':'False', 'message':'Must be TXT file!'})
        return flask.redirect(url_for('home'))
    if not places_exist(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)):
        return flask.jsonify({'result':'False', 'message':'There is an affiliation missing from your Place list. Please re-try.'})
        return flask.redirect(url_for('home'))
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    flask.session['filename'] = filename
    return flask.jsonify({'result':'True'})
```

**UPDATE:**

```
def process_file():
  #here, you can run all the checks as before, but instead of flash, you can return jsonified results to read in the front-end
    if 'file' not in flask.request.files or not flask.request.files['file'].filename:
        return flask.jsonify({'result':'False', 'message':'no files selected'})
        return flask.redirect(url_for('home'))
    file = flask.request.files['file']
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    if not allowed_file(file.filename):
        return flask.jsonify({'result':'False', 'message':'Must be TXT file!'})
        return flask.redirect(url_for('home'))
    # Save the file in the temp folder
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['TEMP_FOLDER'], filename))
    # Process the file 
    if not places_exist(os.path.join(app.config['TEMP_FOLDER'], filename)):
        return flask.jsonify({'result':'False', 'message':'There is an affiliation missing from your Place list. Please re-try.'})
        return flask.redirect(url_for('home'))
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    flask.session['filename'] = filename
    return flask.jsonify({'result':'True'})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read a file before its writing in your directory. First you need to save the file in your application upload directory then read it.

```
def process_file():
    # here, you can run all the checks as before, but instead of flash, you can return jsonified results to read in the front-end
    if 'file' not in flask.request.files or not flask.request.files['file'].filename:
        return flask.jsonify({'result':'False', 'message':'no files selected'})
        return flask.redirect(url_for('home'))
    file = flask.request.files['file']
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    if not allowed_file(file.filename):
        return flask.jsonify({'result':'False', 'message':'Must be TXT file!'})
        return flask.redirect(url_for('home'))
    # Save the file in the correct Location
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    # Process your file already saved
    if not places_exist(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)):
        return flask.jsonify({'result':'False', 'message':'There is an affiliation missing from your Place list. Please re-try.'})
        return flask.redirect(url_for('home'))

    flask.session['filename'] = filename
    return flask.jsonify({'result':'True'})
```

EDIT: You have to be careful if you need to check the file before saving, if you save right away you will override your old file, a good approach will be to save the file in a temp location, check that file and then save in the final directory, and obviously delete the file in the tmp folder.

PS: Also you have 2 return, if you need to respond as a HTML or JSON you have to check the headers of the request.

Comment: Please see my update above. When I try your suggestion of saving the file in a temp folder, scanning it, and then saving it to the actual destination, I get the error `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/temp/Authors_Template.tsv'`.

Comment: @claudiadast did you create the `/temp` folder or tree directory for the files? make sure they exists and the user running flask has the permissions to write in that folder

Comment: @claudiadast is this a relative or absolute path ? /temp it is in your flask application folder or at root? You could be writing in `/temp` or `/route/to/app/temp`

Comment: I resolved the `temp/` issue and the file gets written there. But now the issue I'm having is that Flask doesn't appear to be reading the file properly. I get the error: `File "author_script.py", line 204, in <module>
    p_index = (places_temp.index('Place')) + 1
ValueError: 'Place' is not in list`, which means that the `places_temp` list is empty, because the file isn't getting read. `author_script.py` is the backend python script that processes the downloaded TXT or TSV file and produces an HTML result.